# How to filter using multiple keywords in google sheets or excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm using google sheets, and I've been trying to filter data based on if the B value contains any of multiple keywords. I'm trying to sort account data, and the names aren't consistent, so I can't just say =FILTER(C:C,(B:B="BK's Stuff")+(B:B="Book")). I need something that will take information out of a lot of text like a wild card. What works great for a single entry is:

=FILTER(C:C,SEARCH("BK",B:B))

But I can't figure out how to combine it so it will filter all values that contain EITHER "BK" or "Book."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### You can do it replacing `SEARCH` through a combination of `REGEXMATCH` and `ARRAYFORMULA`

`REGEXMATCH` allows you to search for multiple keywords separated by `|`

### Sample:

`=FILTER(C:C,REGEXMATCH(B:B,"BK|book")=TRUE)`

> Note:
>
> Regexp is case sensitive, so you need to specify separately
>   `REGEXMATCH(B:B,"BK|bk|Bk|bK|")` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Excel:

You can combine several `SEARCH()`s as follows:

```
=FILTER(C1:C20,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Book",B1:B20,1))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BK",B1:B20,1)))
```

[image]

*(should be similar for Google Sheets)*