# Spreadsheet - Combine multiple true results from multiple expressions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am doing a spreadsheet where I have the category and tags column.

I have here an example so I can explain more.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMZVV.png)

So when the tag column has "fashion' in it, the category column should have the "Beauty & Fashion" category. And then if there is a "car" tag, then it should have the "Automotive" category together with the "Beauty & Fashion" and so on..

I have here this code:

```
=textjoin(",",true,ifs(isnumber(search({"fashion","makeup","skincare"},E8)),B4,isnumber(search({"car", "bmw"},E8)),B3))
```

B4 = "Beauty & Fashion"
B3 = "Automotive"

but I think if the first expression is true, it stops on reading the code. so only one category is being put in the cell.

Can someone help me please? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join several strings with `textjoin` the syntax should be

`TEXTJOIN(",",true, text1, text2)`

So:

```
=textjoin(",",true,if(isnumber(search({"fashion","makeup","skincare"},E8)),B4), IF(isnumber(search({"car", "bmw"},E8)),B3))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I just realized that the {} does not work in IF? So it means I need to add in code every single tag I have for every category to be able to make this work? I tried to find simpler solution over the internet but cant find one. Just wanted to know if you have any simpler solution in mind.. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to search for multiple values, you need to replace `search` with `regexp` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61363347/11599789) for a sample.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll study about this one. Thanks!!! Big help!